# convLSTM2D dilation_rate seems not to work

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm trying to do an upsampling using the dilation_rate from the convLSTM2D (Keras with Tenosrflow as backend)

```
input = Input(shape=(10, 64, 64, 1), name='encoder_input')
layer1 = ConvLSTM2D(filters=33, kernel_size=(5,5), dilation_rate=(2, 2))
model = Model(input, layer1(input))
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

I would expect the output shape to be (None,128,128,33) but I got (None,64,64,33).
Wouldn't this dilation_rate=(2, 2) be the opposite to strides=(2, 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dilation, unlike stride, does not change the shape of the data. It simply increases the "spread" of the kernels. In this gif, you can see how it works:

[image]

The only change in the shape of the data comes from cutting off 2 from each side, because no padding is used.